# How to use runtime tracing in OpenMP LLVM?

Tags: c, openmp, llvm, llvm-clang

I want to enable runtime tracing and see the output. Something like the output of

```
KD_TRACE(10, ( buff, gtid, schedule, chunk, lb, ub, st ) );
```

in kmp_dispatch.cpp

Refer this
https://elixir.bootlin.com/llvm/latest/source/openmp/runtime/src/kmp_dispatch.cpp#L624

So, far I have followed the following tutorial:
https://passlab.github.io/CSE436536/Assignments/project_dev_setup.html
But I am not able to see any output from the tracer.

Is there a particular file or something where the output is logged? Or it is logged in the terminal?

I am compiling the openMP program like this:

```
clang omp1.c -L/PATH/llvm_work/openmp/BUILD/runtime/src   -o omp1

ldd omp1
```

This is the output:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdae305000)

libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fca2f3bb000)

/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fca2f7ac000)
```

I hope this is using the OpenMP I have build from source and not libomp.

omp1.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include "omp.h"

int main()
{
    int i=0;
    #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for(i=0;i<1000;++i)
    {
        int x = 4+i;
    }
}
```

But when I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/passlab/CSE436536Project/blob/master/examples/axpy_omp_task.c) program using the same command I am getting an error.

```
/tmp/omp2-d969a9.o: In function `main':

omp2.c:(.text+0x1c8): undefined reference to omp_set_num_threads

clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can anyone help me with correctly compiling the openMP programs with the openMP code I have built from source and also in using tracer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You need to compile with `-fopenmp` flag. Also, you need to have the debug version of the runtime (built with debug info) + set the environment variable `export KMP_DEBUG=511`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to tell the compiler, that you want to use OpenMP via `-fopenmp`:

```
clang -fopenmp omp1.c -L/PATH/llvm_work/openmp/BUILD/runtime/src -o omp1
```